Locklift: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
I've got this error, could you help me to solve it?
npx locklift init -f

X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\ts-mocha\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:322
            return old(m, filename);
                   ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\nekoton-wasm\nekoton_wasm_locklift_main.js from X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\locklift\internal\tracing\tracingInternal.js not supported.
nekoton_wasm_locklift_main.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead either rename nekoton_wasm_locklift_main.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\nekoton-wasm\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\ts-mocha\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:322:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\locklift\internal\tracing\tracingInternal.js:36:24)
    at require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (X:\SmartContracts\ton-smart-contracts\node_modules\ts-mocha\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:322:20)

I have tried to run npx locklift init -f, then it happened.

Hi, the tags need improvement for this question to reach the right audience.  Please search https://stackoverflow.com/tags for tags and hover over the names for descriptions.  java (.java) and javascript (.js) are a separate programming languages with separate library systems, and java seems inappropriate here.  package is vague and not recommended.  install.packages is a about an R language library by that name and seems inappropriate.  npx appears to be an npm (node.js package manager) command, so node.js or node-modules might be more appropriate tags.
